# Can't get this query to work (left outer join) Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I've got this query I'd like to get working. I'm trying to count all the instances of a foreign key after a certain date that isn't null, and then left join that to the distinct of the original table, so I can see the variables with no entries. Here's my query:

```
select fulllist.fk_fc_id 
from 
(
    select distinct fk_fc_id 
    from data_item
) as fulllist 
left outer join
(
    select temp.fk_fc_id, count(*) as number 
    from 
    (
        select * 
        from data_item 
        where di_item_value not like 'Null' 
            and di_timestamp > '2013-11-01 00:00:00'
    )   as temp 
    group by fk_fc_id
)   as lj
    on lj.fc_fk_id=fulllist.fk_fc_id;
```

the error is

> ERROR:  column lj.fc_fk_id does not exist
>
> LINE 19:  on lj.fc_fk_id=fulllist.fk_fc_id;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this is just a typo.  Your subquery is returning `fk_fc_id` but your join is referencing `fc_fk_id`.  It seems like you just need to alter the query:

```
select fulllist.fk_fc_id 
from 
(
    select distinct fk_fc_id 
    from data_item
) as fulllist 
left outer join
(
    select temp.fk_fc_id, count(*) as number 
    from 
    (
        select * 
        from data_item 
        where di_item_value not like 'Null' 
            and di_timestamp > '2013-11-01 00:00:00'
    )   as temp 
    group by fk_fc_id
)   as lj
    on lj.fk_fc_id=fulllist.fk_fc_id;
```

It also seems like you would want to include the `number` in the final select:

```
select fulllist.fk_fc_id, coalesce(lj.number, 0) number
from 
(
    select distinct fk_fc_id 
    from data_item
) as fulllist 
left outer join
(
    select temp.fk_fc_id, count(*) as number 
    from 
    (
        select * 
        from data_item 
        where di_item_value not like 'Null' 
            and di_timestamp > '2013-11-01 00:00:00'
    )   as temp 
    group by fk_fc_id
)   as lj
    on lj.fk_fc_id=fulllist.fk_fc_id;
```

Answer (score 5):

Besides the typo (already found by @blueefet), your query can be simplified:

```
select fk_fc_id,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN di_item_value not like 'Null' 
                        and di_timestamp > '2013-11-01 00:00:00'
                   THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
            ) AS number 
from data_item 
group by fk_fc_id ;
```

Comment: +1; or even just: `di_item_value <> 'Null'`. If that's really meant to exclude actual `NULL` values, then `di_item_value IS NOT NULL`, of course.